# <stringname>.capitalize VS. str.capitalize(<stringname>)

Tags: python, string, class, methods, capitalize

```
str.capitalize(<stringname>)
```

I've recently encountered this permutation of .capitalize method and it confused me a lot. Until now I was taught that methods like .capitalize() or .casefold() do not take any parameters and suddenly I see the strigname as a parameter with str function calling it?

I'd love to know where else I can encounter this and what's the deal behind it. Thanks in advance.